# pytest mock variable calling the actual method

Tags: python, mocking, pytest

I have two files foo.py and bar.py

foo.py

```
NAME  = os.getenv('NAME').lower()
```

bar.py

```
from foo import NAME

def helper():
    print (NAME)
```

I have a test file test/test_name.py

```
import bar
@mock.patch('bar.NAME', "Alice")
def test__get_file(monkeypatch):
  
    print(bar.NAME)
```

Giving an error:

```
../bar.py:6: in <module>
    from foo import NAME
../foo.py:17: in <module>
 

 NAME = os.getenv('NAME').lower()
E   AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

What I am missing?

Comment: The problem is that `foo` is imported before it is patched (the patching itself imports it) and the global statement executed while no variable is set. It would generally be better to handle this in a function, and also to handle the case where the variable does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A per [os module documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#process-parameters), `os.getenv` can return a default value if the environment variable does not exist.

So, you could modify `foo.py` to avoid raising an error when running your test (for the reason given by @MrBeanBremen in his comment) like this:

```py
NAME  = os.getenv('NAME', default="MISSING").lower()
```

Comment: No, I want it to set to some value, it can not be null.

Comment: Not sure to follow. It won't return None if you set a default value in getenv as suggested in the answer, isn't it precisely what you want?

Comment: I handled it ``` with mock.patch.dict("NAME": "Test")``` and I imported ```from foo import NAME ``` under that with context.
I got this idea from @MrBean. Not sure if this is ideal but it worked.